# i3 - share a workspace across multiple monitors

Tags: i3, workspaces

Is it possible to configure a workspace to span multiple monitors OR when I hit a certain key(s) to tell i3 to switch to both workspaces?  Say for example, workspace 1,3,5,7,9 are on monitor 1 and the even ones are on monitor 2.  If I hit 1, I want workspaces 1 and 2 to be visible, if I hit 3, then 3 and 4, etc.

I'm used to how other WM's work and still think that way despite having used i3 for quite some time now.  I mentally group my work that way and this would save me a little bit of a headache.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at "output" command:

workspace 1 output HDMI-0

binds workspace 1 to the Monitor on HDMI-0 (to find with xrandr --listmonitors)